# Laplace expansion sanity check (Hoffman & Kunze)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra (2nd edition) and trying to understand example 13 of section 5.7.  To obtain a Laplace expansion for the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix over a commutative ring $K$ with identity, they say something along the following lines:

Let $r$ be an integer satisfying $1\le r<n$ and let $G$ be the subgroup of the permutation group $S_n$ whose members permutes the sets $\{1, \dots, r\}$ and $\{r+1, \dots, n\}$ within themselves.  Each (left) coset of $G$ in $S_n$ contains exactly one permutation $\sigma$ satisfying $\sigma1<\cdots<\sigma r$ and $\sigma(r+1)<\cdots<\sigma n$, and the sign of this permutation is given by
$$
\mathop{\rm sgn}\sigma=(-1)^{\sigma1+\cdots+\sigma r+(r(r-1)/2)}
$$

I understand why each coset of $G$ contains a unique permutation satisfying the chains of inequalities.  What I don't understand is the sign formula.  For instance, it seems to suggest the sign of the identity permutation is $(-1)^r$ since $r(r-1)/2=1+\cdots+r-1$.  Should $r-1$ be $r+1$?  If so (or not), how do I see the formula holds?